# Vectorized normal distribution python

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, mle

Possibly a dumb question so forgive me but,

From [here](http://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/estimating-custom-mle.html):

```
N = 10000
x = 10 + 2*np.random.randn(N)
y = 5 + x + np.random.randn(N)

def neg_loglike(const,coef,std):
    mu = const + coef*x
    print(mu.shape)
    return -1*stats.norm(mu, std).logpdf(y).sum()

seed = np.array([1,1,1])
res = minimize(neg_loglike, seed, method = 'Nelder-Mead', 
            options={'disp': True})
```

mu is an array/vector in this case - so is `stats.norm` generating a normal distribution for *each value of x*? What does it mean for a normal distribution to have multiple means... (clearly I'm not getting this)

Lastly, is a correct interpretation of the optimal values in `res.x` 
that these parameters generate a set of normal distributions that maximize the probability of seeing y in the distribution..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `norm` accepts a vector of `loc` and `scale` parameters, and treats each input as its own distribution.  Note that it's fine to input a vector for one parameter and a scalar for the other, as is the case in the link you've referenced (where `scale` is `1` and `loc` is the vector `x`).

For example:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

norm(loc=[1,2,3], scale=1).logpdf([4,5,6])
```

Output:

```
array([-5.41893853, -5.41893853, -5.41893853])
```

Comment: sorry and last part of the question - is how to interpret the results of the optimizer

Comment: That's a substantively different question, and isn't really related to coding.  Understanding the results of the Nelder-Mead Simplex in the context of maximum likelihood is a topic better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Glad to help.  If this answer resolved your original question, please mark it resolved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  Good luck with MLE!